# Python Code Error 3.x Malloc

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to retrieve data from www.weather.com and displaying it in my APP. 
I wrote code in Python. But i am getting the following Error.

Python malloc: *** error for object 0x1004d6030: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

How do I avoid this Error

Comment: We can't see what your code is doing if you don't show it to us. Python 3.x is not specific enough -- which version of Python are you using? How do you retrieve the data from www.weather.com?

Comment: I am using python 3.6 and I am getting data through API

Comment: Which API? What does your code look like?